# Escape double quote in formatted string C#

Tags: c#, escaping, string-formatting, stringbuilder, double-quotes

I have a `StringBuilder` to which I am trying to append a formatted string.

Unfortunately, the usual method of escaping double quotes doesn't seem to be working.

```
 StringBuilder sb = New StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendFormat("{0},\"{1}\" and \"{2}\",{3}", stringVariable, stringToQuote, otherStringToQuote, anotherStringVariable)
 sb.AppendLine();


 //resulting text: 
 //item0, item1 and "item2", item3
```

The weird thing is, item {1} does not get quoted, but item {2} does. What is going on here?

**EDIT:**

More information, in case it is relevant: I am writing the contents of the `StringBuilder` to a csv file (comma delimited). The `AppendFormat` call above adds one line to the csv.

Comment: the escape after `{2}` is on the wrong side of the quote

Comment: It works fine by my side. Can you try again now that you've fixed the typo?

Comment: I did try again, still no luck. This is making me crazy.

Comment: Standard programming thing when the code works for someone else, but not for you, wipe out our binaries folder and recompile. Sometimes, you get a stale copy left over.

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo in

```
"{0},\"{1}\" and \"{2}"\,{3}"
```

try

```
"{0},\"{1}\" and \"{2}\",{3}"
```

Comment: Now fixed. This was not the issue, however (Mistake was made when I replaced the content after copying my code).